# Sequelize raw queries TextRow and getting data out of it

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Given this query here,

```js
        let output = [];
        const sql = `select * from coredb.account LIMIT ${offset},${limit}`;
        let data = await sequelize.query(sql, null, {raw: true, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
        data.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(item['id'], item.id); // <-- output says "undefined, undefined"
        });
```

the `data` variable is indeed hydrated with the right row data when using `console.log` to inspect it.

But, when I try to access the individual properties, they only ever come back as `undefined`.  This `TextRow` object that Sequelize seems to return the result in doesn't seem to want to let me access then explicit rows.

Just curious what i'm missing here, am I missing an option?

Comment: Is because you are using `raw: true`

Comment: @Ellebkey even with raw set to false, I get the same result and can't access the individual fields

Answer (score 3):

I agree, Sequalize raw queries are not intuitive. [You don't need](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8889) the `null` or `raw: true` flag. Something like this should work:

```
let data = await sequelize.query(sql, {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
```

Comment: LOL I just tried to vote for this answer 8 months later w/o realizing it was my own.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried this, "data" was an array of two objects, each being the query result.  So, the properties can be accessed by using index [0].... e.g.

```
data[0].forEach((item) => {
   console.log(item['id'], item.id); // <-- output says "undefined, undefined"
});
```

Not yet sure *WHY* this occurs!

EDIT - it's because .query() should have only two arguments.  Changing the call to: `sequelize.query(sql, {raw: true, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})` resulted in data being a single array (as expected).

Comment: If you console.log the 'data' object you can see the anatomy of what sequelize returns

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find the solution for it. 
You just need to make a new array and push data into it by finding bases on key name like this: 
suppose we have data in students object:

```
    let finalArray = new Array();
    for (var k in students ) {
      finalArray.push(students[k])
    }

 console.log(finalArray) // Normal JSON array object :)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 m.sequelize.query(sql, {
          model,
          mapToModel: true
        })
          .then(model => res.status(200).send(model))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error.toString())
        })
```